# Fetch data From Wordpress Database

Tags: wordpress

I am using listify theme and wp job manger field editor addon i am adding one new field and that meta_key field is (_get_the_author_meta) Now data store in database i am fetch data in fornt end Please send me full code how to fetch data through meta_key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get meta value.

```
get_post_meta( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )
```

For more details visit this page.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.